# Entity Framework 5, Code Migration and Package Manager Console

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, nuget

When I attempt to run the Add-Migration command from the package manager console I receive the following error; "The project [project name] failed to build".  I believe the problem is related to the fact that I have to use Apache Ivy as a binary repository which means I can't use nuget or its package structure. If I try to use nuget my csproj files are modified which breaks our internal build script.  Another potential problem could be related to the fact that I have to build in x86 and not Any CPU.

Is there a way in EF5 to generate code migrations without the package manager console? Or can I change the location that package manager looks in for EF tools (I still have the tools directory from the nuget package)?

Comment: Just a thought, make sure that you are pointing to the right project. For example if you have `Domain, Data UnitTests and Web` should point to `Web`

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using the above comment and by removing AnyCPU from the project and solution config.